# Lebesgue Measure as a Countable Sum of Probability Measures

Tags: probability-theory

Show that Lebesgue measure can be expressed as a countable sum of probability measures.

I'm trying to do something with the countable additivity property in order to show this, but so far nothing is working. I don't think this is supposed to be difficult, but I'm not seeing it, so any help you could give would be most appreciated!

Comment: On $\mathbb R$, for any set $E\subset\mathbb R$ with $\mu(E)=1$ ($\mu$ being the Lebesgue measure) you could define the _probability_
$$
\mathcal P_E(A) ~:=~ \mu(A\cap E)
$$
Then  for every measurable set $A$ you would have
$$
\mu(A) ~=~ \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\mathcal P_{[n,n+1)}(A)
$$
On separable spaces like $\mathbb R^n$ you can always find a countable partition of sets $A_n$ with $\mu(A_n)=1$

Comment: Thank you, Andreas, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: For any integer $n,$ note that $0\le\mu\bigl([n,n+1)\cap A)\le 1$ for any measurable set $A\subseteq R.$

Comment: Thank you! Between the two of you, I think I have a good grasp of it now.